# Printing string from array prints wrong result

Tags: arrays, c, string, printing

Hey I was wondering if I could get some help on this. I have an array that was given to me like this:

`char **indexArray;`

And I was told to add to the array like this:

`indexArray[recCount++]=root->data;`

recCount isn't important, but essentially, when I do this, I tried this:

```
printf(indexArray[recCount]);
printf(root->data);
```

Yet for some reason, the output is this:

```
ðy
test
```

Anyone know why?

Edit: @MikeCAT
My node setup is as follows:

```
    numNodes += 1;

    struct bNode *node = (bNode *) malloc(sizeof(bNode));
    node->data = data;
    node->left  = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    printf(node->data); #prints the data I want so this works just fine
    return node;
}
```

Then I do something along the lines of:

`bNode root = makeNode("test")`

then I do this:

`indexArray[recCount++]=root->data;`

Yet when I do this:

`printf("%s", indexArray[0]);`

I either get some random character, (null), or just a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `recCount++` is add one to `recCount` and evaluated to the value of `recCount` *before the addition*.

Therefore, you should use `indexArray[recCount-1]` instead of `indexArray[recCount]` to get the assigned value after that.

Also

```
printf(indexArray[recCount]);
printf(root->data);
```

looks dangerous because it will interpret `%` in the data as format specifier and invoke *undefined behavior* because there are not data corresponding to the specifiers if it is included.

It should be

```
printf("%s", indexArray[recCount]);
printf("%s", root->data);
```

or

```
fputs(indexArray[recCount], stdout);
fputs(root->data, stdout);
```

Comment: My node setup is as follows:
`struct bNode *makeNode(char *data) {
    numNodes += 1;

    struct bNode *node = (bNode *) malloc(sizeof(bNode));
    node->data = data;
    node->left  = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    printf(node->data); #prints the data I want so this works just fine
    return node;
}`
Then I do something along the lines of:

`bNode root = makeNode("test")`

then I do this:

`indexArray[recCount++]=root->data;`

Yet when I do this:

`printf("%s", indexArray[0]);`

I either get some random character, (null), or just a blank line.

Comment: any ideas of how to fix this please?